# Change drive permissions on dual boot machine

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive, fedora

I have a dual boot machine, with Ubuntu and Fedora. It has an internal drive that I want to use for storing Ardour files. The drive is owned by Ubuntu, and does not contain the operating systems. I want to give the Fedora boot read/write/delete access to the drive. How do I do that? BTW, this drive does not auto-mount.

Comment: I would suggest adding the partition to /etc/fstab and mount it on your fedora system (to a non-system directory); 'noauto' if you want.

Comment: I don't think an OS can own a drive, per se. You probably just need to set it up in the fstab in Fedora.

Comment: I second @wjandrea thoughts.